# Globbaly Host a webservice of C#

Tags: c#, android, web-services, web-hosting

I have created a webservice in c# which I want to call in my Android application. I want to host this webservice globally**(free, as this is only for testing purpose)**, so that it can be easily call. I have done some google and I found this link usefull:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/

But I am not sure if the **WindowsAzure** will provide me free hosting or not.

I want some more options.

Might be this is some off-topic question, but I am new in hosting and this is some how important for me. Please help.

**Update**

I want free web hosting sites, not paid as I already mentioned above.

**2nd Update**

https://cloud.google.com/products/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=appengine-search-global

Found one more link but also not sure about that it will provide free web hosting!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot and atlast I find a site:

http://www.aspspider.com/

This is very easy for the new users. I have just succesfully host my webservice here.